# 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH / Python / Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://www.iplogger.ru/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\Hacker'sTools\\core\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")

try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(5)

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)

finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Hacker's Tools\core\chromedriver\main.py", line 31, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Hacker's Tools\core\chromedriver.exe")
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: а chromedriver точно находится по указанному пути?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/W8gRfui

Comment: зачем указывать путь к `chromedriver` если он лежит рядом с `main.py` который его же и вызывает?

Comment: спасибо! Но вылетает ошибка в самом хроме о том, что браузером управляет незнакомое ПО, как отключить? Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: приведите скриншот указанной в комментарии ошибки

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CvEpxTP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57304986/12785139

Comment: СПАСИБО!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оставлю ответ, т.к. в поиске не показывается кол-во комментариев.

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что указан полный путь к `chromedriver` несмотря на то, что он находится в том же каталоге что и `main.py` вызывающий его.

А для скрытия бара "Браузером Chrome управляет автоматизированное тестовое ПО." требуется указать опции:

```
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57304986/12785139)