# Как сделать, чтобы браузер работал в фоновом режиме?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, macos

Хочу, чтобы браузер работал в фоновом режиме!

**Код:**

```
from os import name
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import sys 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys  import Keys
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
startTime = datetime.now()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/olesa/Downloads/chromedriver') 



chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

with webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) as driver:
driver.get('https://www.lamoda.ru/p/rtlaan778401/shoes-adidasoriginals-krossovki/')
assert "Python" in driver.title
print(driver.title)
```

**Ошибка:**

```
Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Я видел много ответов на этот вопрос, но я не понимал как все таки решить! Если что, работаю с **macOS**.

Comment: @gil9red это macos, там нет букв диска.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, ага, не заметил :)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1302878/234134 / https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141300/234134